# Show/hide element AngularJS based on Controller boolean variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am trying to hide/show a portion of a form based on a Controller boolean variable. this is my html code:

```
<div id="sheetform-container" ng-controller="SheetController as SheetCtrl">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="sheetform-row" ng-show="canShow('Price')">
      <div class="sheetform-left-col fl-left"><label for="sheetform-price">Price</label></div>
      <div class="sheetform-midlle-col fl-left"><input type="text" class="sheetform-input" id="sheetform-price" name="price" value="$ 0.00" /></div>
      <div class="sheetform-right-col fl-right"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have created a function that changes the Price attribute to true/false according to the value sent, its called setConfig. This is how the Controller code looks like:

```
ngApp.controller('SheetController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.Price = true;

    $scope.canShow = function(field) {
        return $scope.Price;
    }

    $scope.setConfig = function(config) {
        $scope.Price = config.Price;
    }
}]);
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are intending for price to be the actual price of something then you shouldn't be using that for the boolean in this case. Assign the price using `ng-model`. Also, don't use a capital letter to name a variable. Only classes should be capitalized.

```
<div id="sheetform-container" ng-controller="SheetController as SheetCtrl">
  <form action="#">
    <div class="sheetform-row" ng-show="showPrice">
      <div class="sheetform-left-col fl-left"><label for="sheetform-price">Price</label></div>
      <div class="sheetform-midlle-col fl-left"><input type="text" class="sheetform-input" id="sheetform-price" name="price" ng-model="price" /></div>
      <div class="sheetform-right-col fl-right"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then in your controller you can remove the function you have and also initialize the variables

```
ngApp.controller('SheetController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.showPrice = true;
    $scope.price = null;

}]);
```

I'm not sure how you are determining whether the price should be shown or not but you can either have $scope.showPrice assigned to a property in whatever object the form is for or if it's a toggle then you can just say:

```
<a href ng-click="showPrice = !showPrice"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `<div class="sheetform-row" ng-show="canShow('Price')">`
canShow() function needs a boolean value so that ng-show can change the output accordingly.

'Price' is treated as a string 'Price' not a boolean in your controller.

So change it to `ng-show="canShow(Price)"`,here Price's value will be true/false ,this will help ng-show  to hide/show properly.

Also setConfig is not influencing the value of price right now.

Let me know if it helps you or u need further help.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing $digest().
angular only updates DOM in digest loop.

[official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

[$watch how $apply runs $digest](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/)